# Calculating the area of a triangle

Tags: java

I am new to Java. I am trying to calculate the area of a triangle using the formula:

s = (side 1 + side 2 + side 3)/2

area = square root (side (side - side 1)(side - side2)(side - side3).

If the user enter the three point as:
1.5 -3.4 4.6 5 9.5 -3.4 then the area of the triangle should be 33.6. However, my program runs, but it's giving me an incorrect answer. Below is my code.

```
// Import Java Scanner
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.lang.Math;
public class Ex_2_19 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    //Create a Scanner object
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    float side = 0;
    float area1 = 0;
    float area2 = 0;
    float area3 = 0;
    float area4 = 0;
    float calculatedarea = 0;

    //Prompt the user to enter three points of a triangle
    System.out.println("Enter point x1:");
    System.out.println("Enter point y1:");
    System.out.println("Enter point x2:");
    System.out.println("Enter point y2:");
    System.out.println("Enter point x3:");
    System.out.println("Enter point y3:");

    //Define the variables
    float Pointx1 = input.nextFloat();
    float Pointy1 = input.nextFloat();
    float Pointx2 = input.nextFloat();
    float Pointy2 = input.nextFloat();
    float Pointx3 = input.nextFloat();
    float Pointy3 = input.nextFloat();

    //Formula to calculate the area of a triangle
    side = (Pointx1 + Pointy1 + Pointx2 + Pointy2 + Pointx3 + Pointy3) / 2;
    area1 = side - (Pointx1 + Pointy1);
    area2 = side - (Pointx2 + Pointy2);
    area3 = side - (Pointx3 + Pointy3);
    area4 = side * area1 * (area2) * (area3);
    calculatedarea = (float) (Math.sqrt(area4)); 
    //calculatedarea = (float) (Math.sqrt(area1)*(area2) * (area3)); 

    //Print result
    System.out.println("The area of the triangle is " + calculatedarea);


}
```

}

Comment: The formula you're using works on the lengths of the sides of the triangle. You're just adding up the X and Y coordinates of each point - nothing to do with the length at all.

Comment: Based on https://www.mathsisfun.com/geometry/herons-formula.html, find the lengths a, b,c by calculating distance between each pair of xy coordinates. The way you are calculating area1, 2, 3 4 seems to be wrong.

Answer (score 3):

You are trying [`Heron's Formula`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heron%27s_formula) - note that `a`, `b`, `c` are the **euclidean distance** between the points, thus will need to be computed by `sqrt((x1 - x2) * (x1 - x2) + (y1 - y2) * (y1 - y2))`, etc., not just the sum of differences.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // Create Scanner
        var in = new Scanner(System.in);


        // Ask user to Enter the six Point

        System.out.print("Enter Three Point for a Triangle : ");

        //( X1,Y1 )
        double x1 = in.nextDouble();

        double y1 = in.nextDouble();

        // ( X2 ,Y2 )
        double x2 = in.nextDouble();

        double y2 = in.nextDouble();

        // ( X3 , Y3 )
        double x3 = in.nextDouble();

        double y3 = in.nextDouble();

        // first sum between group 1 and 2

        double side1 = DistanceBetweenToPoint(x1, y1, x2, y2);

        // Second sum between group 2 and 3

        double side2 = DistanceBetweenToPoint(x2, y2, x3, y3);

        // third sum between group 1 and 3

        double side3 = DistanceBetweenToPoint(x1, y1, x3, y3);

        // The Formula of s

        double s = (side1 + side2 + side3) / 2;

        // The Formula of Area

        double area = Math.pow(((s * (s - side1)) * (s - side2) * (s - side3)), 0.5);

        System.out.printf("The area of the Triangle is %s", area);

    }

    // make distance between tow point

    static double DistanceBetweenToPoint(double x1, double y1, double x2, double y2) {

        // Calc Distance between two Point

        return Math.pow((Math.pow((x2 - x1), 2) + Math.pow((y2 - y1), 2)), 0.5);

    }

}
```